# How to deploy SharePoint 2010 Sandbox solution on SharePoint 2013 Office 365

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, 2013, visual-web-part, office-365

I have developed a SharePoint 2010 Sandbox solution in Visual Studio 2012 which has been deployed on Office 365 SP2010. The solution contains custom lists, visual web parts and workflow activities.

I now want to deploy it to Office 365 SP2013 but face some problems doing that.

I have tried to deploy the .WSP file to Office 365 SP2013 but deployment failed.

Then I created a new SP2013 project in Visual Studio 2012 and imported all the files from my existing project. I got to the stage where I could deploy the .WSP file successfully to Office 365 SP2013 but a lot of the functionality didn't work. Some of the issues are:

- Web parts throw errors
- If applying my custom master page it's complete screw up the site and throws errors

My question is not specific for the issues listed but more of a general question if anyone have experienced similar issues and what steps they took to solve it. I haven't been able to find any official documents from Microsoft on how to migrate a SP2010 Sandbox solution to SP2013.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your 2010 master page to work in O365 Preview, go to the site collection and disable the 'Minimal Download Strategy' web-scoped feature. Then you would have to update the master page's CSS to point it to v5 specific CSS.

as:

```
<!-- OOTB CSS & Theme -->
<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="15"/>
<SharePoint:Theme runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" />
```

then you may have to play with the CSS to make it look perfect.